# MATLAB: how to include running time on a graph?

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab, octave

I have a MATLAB/Octave program for which I used the `tic` and `toc` functions to measure the time elapsed for some calculations. e.g.:

> tic();
>     for k=1:200
>         ...
>         ...
>     end
>     time=toc();

so now I have the value `time`.

> how can I include this (anywhere and anyhow) automatically on a plot? as a legend? as a label? as a title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `num2str`-function. To display time in the title use for example:

> title(['running time  ' num2str(time) 's'])